# Using bash find how can I ignore all file extensions if present?

Tags: macos, bash, find

Say I have this in a directory:

```
master3.txt
master3
master3old
anotherFile
```

and I need to use find to return:

```
master3.txt
master3
```

Basically it means using find and ignoring file extensions if present. The key thing in this example is to not return "master3old"

I want to use `find` on Mac OS X so I can then run `-exec cp` on the result.

Comment: What is the requirement for `master3-new`?  Not returned?

Comment: @Jonathan `master3-new` must not returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $DIR -name "master3*" | grep "master3\>" | xargs
```

where `$DIR` is the directory being searched.  `\>` indicates the end of word.

Comment: I'm on mac os 10.8 and returning nothing with the above unfortunately.

Comment: It worked fine on Mac OS 10.7 for me.  You can try replacing grep with egrep though it should not matter.

Comment: It's worth noting that this also matches things like `foo~1` and `foo backup.txt`, and that it will not be able to copy filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: @unxnut Is there a way of getting an array working with this approach `find "$sourceDir" -type f -name "${SOURCELIST*}" | grep "${SOURCELIST\>}"`

Comment: You can do this using a loop.  For example, for i in ${SOURCELIST} ; do ; find "$sourceDir" -type f -name $i | grep "${i}\>" ; done

Answer (score 2):

Use extglob:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp master3?(.*) /somewhere
```

It matches `master3` optionally followed by `.something`

Comment: +1 nice. in many cases, bash's extended globbing (and globstar( removes the need to call out to find.

Answer (score 0):

check your find man page, see if it has the `-regex` option

```
find . -regex '.*/master3\(\..*\)?'
```

Comment: That didn't work for me on Mac OS 10.8 although there is a `-E` switch which points to regular expressions...